# Tearing down the current JS Context in react-native

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm using Relay with React-Native and need a way to reset my Relay Store when a user logs out of their account. Joe Savona (a dev at facebook) suggests "a brute-force equivalent of a page refresh - tear down the current JS context and start a new one." (See [here](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/233#issuecomment-161884723) for the full issue).

Does anyone know how to go about doing this within React-Native while running on iOS? My guess is that this involves tinkering with some of the Objective-C code, with which I'm a total newbie.

Comment: Hello can share how did you actually did that finally? I created a native module and then tried to call reload method on self.bridge but gives me error.